# Pycharm Command Line Codes

Tags: python, parsing, pycharm, command-line-arguments

I recently just downloaded PyCharm, and I want to get to know it better, however, codes that I would normally run through the terminal, like an argument parser, I no longer know how to do. Here is an example of what I would put into my command line:

```
python read_in_data -w wide_data_set -s row_number -o output_path
```

This would then run the code with my given arguments.

Any basic tips on PyCharm would be helpful, as I am very new to it.

Answer (score 0):

(Top of your screen) Go to Run > Edit Configurations, then enter the command line arguments into the "Script parameters" box. These will then be used when you run the code.

For basic tips/an intro to PyCharm - see the [tutorial videos](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/01/introducing-getting-started-with-pycharm-video-tutorials/) on their website.